# Copy Bytecode of Method to Another Method Using Javassist

Tags: java, bytecode, javassist, bytecode-manipulation

I am using **Javassist** to manipulate the **bytecode** of a .*class* file. i have to retrieve & modify the bytecode of existing method and write the new bytecode to new method.

Suppose i have a method Method_old() in my class file having the following bytecode

> ```
>    0: bipush        10
>    2: istore_1
>    3: bipush        20
>    5: istore_2
>    6: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
>    9: iload_1
>   10: invokevirtual #11                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
>   13: return
> ```

and i want to modify it as given below,

> ```
>    0: bipush        10
>    2: istore_1
>    3: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
>    6: iload_1
>    7: invokevirtual #11                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
>    8: return
> ```

and Store it to a new Method named method_new(). How Can I do so using the Javassist.

Comment: Did you check [Javassist’s Bytecode level API](http://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/tutorial/tutorial3.html#intro)? I’d prefer ASM for such a job, but that’s just me. Besides that, don’t call it “copy” when you do not actually want to copy…

Comment: @Holger thanks for response, i have already checked your given link, the best code at that site is as under,       **CodeIterator ci = ... ;
while (ci.hasNext()) {
    int index = ci.next();
    int op = ci.byteAt(index);
    System.out.println(Mnemonic.OPCODE[op]);
}    **   which just copies OPCODES but misses its operand. any other solution please ?

Comment: Well, since `ci.next()` returns the *index* of the next instruction, all bytes between an index and its next index belong to the instruction and can be queried with `byteAt`, `s16bitAt​`, etc. That's indeed very lowlevel. As said, I'd rather use the ASM library for such tasks, but I tried to point to potential solutions within the scope of your question first, instead of immediately advertising a different library. But if you don't stick to Javassist, you might check http://asm.ow2.org/doc/tutorial-asm-2.0.html

Comment: @Holger Thanks, i am working on your directions and will let you know in case of any other issue.